# Не понимаю как это выражение риадизует формулу хеширвоания методом умножения

Tags: c, структуры, хеширование, структуры-данных, формулы

Эта функций реализует формулу хеширования методом умножения

```
unsigned short HashFunc(unsigned short key, unsigned short tableSize){
    unsigned w = 65535;
    unsigned A = 65534;
    unsigned  m = sqrt(tableSize);
    return (A * key) >> (w - m);
}
```

w - максимальный размер ключа;
A - взаимно простое число, числу w; m - тепень двойки от размера таблицы; key - ключ

Я не понимаю,как такая запись `(A * key) >> (w - m)` может реализововать эту формулу [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

формулу и эквиволетную ей запись на си взял из университетской методчики.
Вот сама методичка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *m - степень двойки от размера таблицы* - а в коде `m` - квадратный корень от размера таблицы

Comment: @user7860670, в любом случае, не могу понять, как это работает